# Deriving style from base style fails WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I just realized that deriving from default style fails in my WPF app and I have no idea, why. Actually it works, but only due to "Hot reload". So I have:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="TestStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"/>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

in resource dictionary, and:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}">
    <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>I want to cry with blood</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

in my control. When I start app I see following:


[image: incorrect view]


And when I remove `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"` and add it again, I have correct view:


[image]

What can be a reason of such behavior? Seems like WPF bug, but I don't think this is possible

Comment: command buttons (New, Open, Save, ...) will look cooler if you place them in UniformGrid: `<UniformGrid Row="1"><Button Content="New"/><Button Content="Open"/></UniformGrid>`

Comment: thanks for advice, this is just temp layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find correct style you need to define it before "TestStyle"

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="TestStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
```